# Не записывает в БД

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Вот код собственно говоря:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once("admin.php");
if(isset($_POST['step']) == "4") {
    $obj_db = new DB();
    $title_product = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $name_product = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name_product'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $price = htmlspecialchars($_POST['price'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $img_product = htmlspecialchars($_POST['img_product'], ENT_QUOTES);
    if($_FILES["img_product"]["size"] > 1024*3*1024)
    {
        echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
        exit();
    }
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_product"]["tmp_name"]))
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_product"]["tmp_name"], "../media/img/products/".$_FILES["img_product"]["name"]);
    } else {
        echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
    }
    $message_pay = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message_pay'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $save_product = $obj_db->DQ("INSERT INTO `products`(`title_name`,`name_product`,`price`,`img_product`,`message_pay`) VALUES('$title_product','$name_product','$price','$_FILES[img_product][name]','$message_pay')");
    if($save_product == 'TRUE') {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Продукт успешно добавлен!');location.href='products.php';</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Сбой в базе данных. Проверьте подключение.');location.href='products.php';</script>";
    }
}
?>
<center><h2>Добавить продукт</h2></center>
<table border="0">
    <form method="POST" action="add_product.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title_name" value="" class="text" maxlength="32" placeholder="пр. book, flow" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h>Идентификатор продукта (напр. book, flower, stainless)</h>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name_product" value="" class="text" maxlength="32" placeholder="Название" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h>Название продукта</h>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="price" value="" placeholder="Цена" class="text" maxlength="32" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h>Цена продукта</h>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="img_product">
            </td>
            <td>
                <h>Выберите изображение продукта</h>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <textarea cols="140" rows="5" name="message_pay" placeholder="Сообщение после оплаты продукта"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4" />
                <input type="submit" value="Добавить продукт" class="btn" />
                <input type="button" value="Отмена" onclick="location.href='products.php';" class="btn" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

С таблицей в БД всё сходится, данные записываются не все. данные перед заносом в БД - выводил, они передаются, но пишутся не все. В чём косяк?[image: Вот тут какие пустые поля - те и не пишутся]

Comment: Сделайте так: `$sql = "INSERT INTO products... VALUES..."; echo $sql; $save_product = $obj_db->DQ($sql);` (пропуски, естественно, заполнить). Потом ручками выполняете выведенный запрос и ищите в нем ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Общее правило: выводите/сохраняйте где-либо SQL-запросы, которые генерируются и выполняются в скрипте, и после "исследуйте" их глазами, выполните их в СУБД вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас в вашем коде так:

```
$save_product = $obj_db->DQ("INSERT INTO `products`(`title_name`,`name_product`,`price`,`img_product`,`message_pay`)

VALUES('$title_product','$name_product','$price','$_FILES[img_product][name]','$message_pay')");
```

Попробуйте так (не уверен):

```
$save_product = $obj_db->DQ("INSERT INTO products (title_name, name_product, price, img_product, message_pay) 
VALUES($title_product, $name_product, $price, $_FILES[img_product][name], $message_pay)");
```

Comment: не помогло.. Не могу понять в чём проблема

Comment: Я вправил только что код, попробуйте сейчас